# tikz figure centering doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want the below code in the center but \begin{center} and \end{center} doesn't work here.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.4]
\def\nx{12}
\def\ny{12}
\foreach \i in {0, ..., \nx}{
    \fill (0:13+\i) ++ (-60:\i) ++ (-120:\i) coordinate (f\i) circle (2pt) node[right] {\small$f_{\i}$}; %node[right] {\i};
}
\foreach \j in {0, ..., \ny}{
    \fill (0:11-\j) ++ (-60:\j) ++ (-120:\j) coordinate (e\j) circle (2pt) node[left]{\small$e_{\j}$}; % node[left] (e\j) {\j};
}
\draw (f0) -- (f12);
\draw (e0) -- (e12);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

It gives me left-shifted figure instead of centered figure. Can you help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the way you find the points where to draw your things. I will show you do this:

1. Build a correct MWE (because the class *will* affect the result)
2. Add `[showframe]{geometry}` package to see the page outlines
3. add an `\fbox` around your picture to show the size of the picture
4. finally, I am adding a line to the path movement `(0:13+\i) ++ (-60:\i) ++ (-120:\i)` (and changing the fill to a draw to be able to see anything).

As you can see, you move right then left; Ti*k*Z does not know that you do not want to have those points in the picture (they are on a path!), so it sets the bounding box to consider them.

So yes, your picture is centered; what is not centered is your drawing *inside* the picture.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.4]
            \def\nx{12}
            \def\ny{12}
            \foreach \i in {0, ..., \nx}{
                \draw (0:13+\i) -- ++ (-60:\i) -- ++ (-120:\i) coordinate (f\i) circle (2pt) node[right] {\small$f_{\i}$}; %node[right] {\i};
            }
            \foreach \j in {0, ..., \ny}{
                \fill (0:11-\j) ++ (-60:\j) ++ (-120:\j) coordinate (e\j) circle (2pt) node[left]{\small$e_{\j}$}; % node[left] (e\j) {\j};
            }
            \draw (f0) -- (f12);
            \draw (e0) -- (e12);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One possible solution, as commented before, is to manually reset the bounding box ([manual here](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.8)):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering %better than {center} environment, no vertical spurious space
        \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.4]
            \def\nx{12}
            \def\ny{12}
            \foreach \i in {0, ..., \nx}{
                \path (0:13+\i) -- ++ (-60:\i) -- ++ (-120:\i) coordinate (f\i) circle (2pt) node[right] {\small$f_{\i}$}; %node[right] {\i};
            }
            \foreach \j in {0, ..., \ny}{
                \fill (0:11-\j) ++ (-60:\j) ++ (-120:\j) coordinate (e\j) circle (2pt) node[left]{\small$e_{\j}$}; % node[left] (e\j) {\j};
            }
            \draw (f0) -- (f12);
            \draw (e0) -- (e12);
            %% take responsibility for the bounding box
            \pgfresetboundingbox
            \draw [use as bounding box]
                ([shift={(-2,2)}] e12 |- f0) rectangle ([shift={(2,-2)}] f12);
            %% Notice the use of the perpendicular coordinate system here
            %% and a shift added to avoid clipping labels.
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following:

[image: image centered with the manual setting of bounding box]

The other solution is to use [Juan Castaño's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683236/38080) and simplify the way you build your figure.

Answer (score 3):

A solution complementary to Romano's answer (+1), which I agree with.

Something a little more simple could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}    % dummy text
\usepackage{showframe} % to show the page geometry
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\def\nx{12}
\foreach\i in{0,...,\nx}
{
    \fill (0: 1) ++ (-60 :2*\i) coordinate (f\i) circle (2pt) node[right] {\small$f_{\i}$};
    \fill (0:-1) ++ (-120:2*\i) coordinate (e\i) circle (2pt) node[left]  {\small$e_{\j}$};
}
\draw (f0) -- (f12);
\draw (e0) -- (e12);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your image is centered in the text block, but you should take a care that image will not be wider than `\textwidth`.

However, for your figure I would consider:

- instead of `center` environment I would rather use command `\centering`, inserted immediately after `\begin{figure}`
- for image code I would adapt my answer on your previous question:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,
dot/.append style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,
                     label=#1}
                     ]
\def\nx{12}
\def\ny{12}
\foreach \i in {0, ..., \nx}
{
    \path (0:25-\i) ++ (80:\i) ++ (100:\i) node (f\i) [dot=right:$f_\i$] {};
}
\foreach \j in {0, ..., \ny}
{
    \path (0:\j)   ++ (80:\j) ++ (100:\j) node (e\j) [dot=left:$e_\j$] {};
}
\draw (f0) -- (f12);
\draw (e0) -- (e12);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)